# Can I use an Android Studio emulator without internet access?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

Basically, I have the same problem as this user (although I'm using Windows and not Linux): [Android Studio emulator doesn't start without internet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73741087/android-studio-emulator-doesnt-start-without-internet)

The thread got no replies and I didn't want to spam the comment section because I didn't have an answer to offer.

If I try to start an emulator in Android Studio but have no internet connection, it shows "waiting for all devices to come online" and nothing happens. The emulator does not start.

Like with the user in the other thread, if I start it with internet access, cut the Wifi and keep using the emulator, it works without problems and I can update apps, even though I don't have an internet connection anymore.

Is it possible the use an emulator when you are not connected to the internet?

Answer (score 0):

Internet is not mandatory to open an emulator in Android Studio unless you haven't created the device already. You can try following to fix it:

1. Go to File -> Invalidate Caches... or Invalidate Caches & Restart
2. [Waiting for Target Device to Come Online](https://Updated%20BMI%20weight%20value%20issue%20fixed%20in%20CV%20App%20%5BDone%5D%20Record%20Time%20Spent%20validation%20in%20CV%20App%20%5BDone%5D%20ACP%20alert%20center%20with%20expiry%20Bendita%20wecare%20Broadway%20Liverpool%202298%20%5BDone%5D%20Smoking%20Alert%20pop%20%5BDone%5D%20Redesign%20Alert%20Pop%20(ZQ)%202076%20%5BDone%5D%5BHTML%20not%20updated%20in%20API%5D%20Add%20red%20asterisk%20in%20mandatory%20fields%20in%20ABC%20App%202325%20%5BDone%5D%20Loading%20local%20data%20in%20offline%20mode%20for%20Dashboard%20Quicklinks%5BDone%5D)

Comment: Thank you! I can't try it right now because I don't have access to my other laptop at the moment. I'll let you know if it worked later on.